# Chrome master preferences

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, protractor, end-to-end, e2e-testing

I'm writing  a protractor test that opens new tabs (in Chrome).
because Chrome settings are per user and the instance that opened by Protractor is anonymous - the pop-up settings are set to block all, so the test fails. I want to set setting for all users.

I've understood that I suppose to set the 'master_preference' file that supposed to be located under `/library/Google` (on Mac OX) and I don't find that file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to let your Chrome know that you don't want the popups being blocked by setting the [`--disable-popup-blocking` argument](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/browser-setup.md#adding-chrome-specific-options):

```
capabilities: {
  browserName: 'chrome',
  chromeOptions: {
    args: ['disable-popup-blocking']
  }
},
```

Comment: thanks, but it doesn't work for me for some reason. I've tried different versions (adding '=true' and adding apostrophes) and it is still blocked.

Comment: OK, apparently I had a problem with reading the capabilities, and you were right as always. great answer. didn't know that option. thanks a lot!